# Grails create criteria not in list

Tags: grails

how to get list A where not use in domain B?

Domain A

```
Class A{
String name
String code
}
```

Domain B

```
Class B{
A aaa
String description
}
```

example data:

```
**domain A**

id+versioin+name   +code+|
1 | 0      |Bobby  |bob  |
2 | 0      |anto   |ant  |
3 | 0      |Jessica|jes  |
4 | 0      |hera   |her  |

**domain B**    
id+version|a_id|description + |
1 | 0     | 1  |this is bobby |
2 | 0     | 3  |this is jessic|
```

how can i get list from A where not used in B.

```
i tried this
def b = B.list()
def c = A.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    not { 'in'(b) }
}
```

but fail..

Comment: try def b = B.list()*.a

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def b = B.list()
def c = A.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    not { 'in'("id",b*.aaa.id) }
}
```

Comment: The performance of this will not be as good as the solution that works in Grails 2.4 as above, because you are performing 2 queries instead of one. Also if you `aaa` association lazy you may have a N+1 problem.

Comment: then whats the solusion?

Comment: but i'm using grails 2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, note in Grails 2.4 (which is at the RC phase and about to go GA) you can write this query as a single query using a subquery, which will perform better:

```
  def c = A.createCriteria()
  def results = c.list {
      notIn new DetachedCriteria(B).id
  }
```

Comment: is this still the preferred solution with grails 3 -- or there's another better solution ?